# How to Fix The Error When There Is An Error After Building The Project Dlls to Another Directory?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2005, build

How to Fix The Error When There  Is An Error After Building The Project Dlls to Another Directory?

```
Error 39 Unable to copy file access is denied
```

For Example:

```
Error   1   Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\fAppCreditService.dll" to "..\..\..\..\..\2005\2005.Application\bin\fAppCreditService.dll".
```

The process cannot access the file '..........\2005\2005.Application\bin\fAppCreditService.dll' because it is being used by another process.   fAppCreditService

I use XP
Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually means that the file is inaccessible. 
It is usually due to not having permissions to write to that directory, or the file being locked.

The file will be locked if an existing copy of your application is running, and the dll is in use by your application.  Close any running copies of the application and re-build the solution.

If your application is not running, make sure that you have write permissions to the directory you are trying to output to.